# Write regex for pincode of 6 digits ie. Indian Pincode

Tags: python, regex, jupyter-notebook

I want to make a regex which can detect pincode from Indian address. The problem is that after giving full address as input, it is taking first 6 digits of mobile number also. So, I want to make it in such a way that it should only detect pincode  but no digit from mobile number.

The regex I tried is:

```
([1-9]{1}[0-9]{5}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\\s[0-9]{3})
```

The address pattern is
`House No. XXXX, Sector 9, CITY NAME, STATENAME - XXXXXX, Mob. No.- 9999XXXXXX`,
one sample:
`House No. 322/4, Salah, Sundernagar, Distt. mandi, Himachal Pradesh - 175018(Pincode), Mob. No. - 9999999999`

Comment: Could you provide multiple examples? (without XXX but with real cases). You can also remplace `[1-9]{1}` by `[1-9]` to shorten the regex. What are the postal rules for India? and what are the phone number rules also?

Comment: The real address example is: House No. 322/4, Salah, Sundernagar, Distt. mandi, Himachal Pradesh - 175018(Pincode), Mob. No. - 9999999999

Comment: The postal rules for india are that it should be only 6 digit number and not starting from 0. The phone number rules are that it should be strictly 10 digit number and India country code is +91. So, mobile number becomes +919999999999

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `\b` before and after your regex, so that we don't match
part of numbers. `\b` is for word-**b**oundary:

`\b[1-9]\d{5}\b`

I replaced `[0-9]` by `\d` for **d**igit as it's more common. But you can
leave `[0-9]` if you prefer it.

In action: https://regex101.com/r/XyDm6G/1

If you want to handle the pincode format `123 456` then you can change
the regex to:

`\b[1-9]\d{2}\s?\d{3}\b`

In action: https://regex101.com/r/XyDm6G/2

Comment: Welcome! I added the optional space between the 3 and 3 digits, for the pincode format `123 456`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace phone number with digits

```
import re
inp='House No. XXXX, Sector 9, CITY NAME, STATENAME - 500050, 090908 Mob. No.- 999XXXXXXX'
pt=re.compile(r'\b(?!0)\d{6}\b')
ma=pt.findall(inp)
print(ma)
```

Output:

```
['500050']
```

Answer (score -1):

This regex will only detect the pincode and not match any digits from the mobile number.

```
\b\d{6}\b
```

Explanation:

- `\b`: Word boundary to match the pattern as a whole word.
- `\d{6}`: Matches exactly 6 digits (pincode format).

Comment: Indian Postal Index Numbers cannot start with zero